# Multiple CSS background gradients

Tags: html, css, background, gradient

I'd like to have multiple gradients on the background of a div.

The first:

```
background-color: #AD0818;
background-image: linear-gradient(transparent 50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .1) 50%);
```

Which creates a two tone red background.

I then want this to fade to transparency left-to-right, this does it without the two tones:

```
background: -moz-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(173,8,24,1) 33%, rgba(173,8,24,0.57) 62%, rgba(255,255,255,0.16) 89%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%);
background: -webkit-gradient(left top, right bottom, color-stop(33%, rgba(173,8,24,1)), color-stop(62%, rgba(173,8,24,0.57)), color-stop(89%, rgba(255,255,255,0.16)), color-stop(100%, rgba(255,255,255,0)));
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(173,8,24,1) 33%, rgba(173,8,24,0.57) 62%, rgba(255,255,255,0.16) 89%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%);
background: -o-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(173,8,24,1) 33%, rgba(173,8,24,0.57) 62%, rgba(255,255,255,0.16) 89%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(173,8,24,1) 33%, rgba(173,8,24,0.57) 62%, rgba(255,255,255,0.16) 89%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%);
background: linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(173,8,24,1) 33%, rgba(173,8,24,0.57) 62%, rgba(255,255,255,0.16) 89%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ad0818', endColorstr='#ffffff', GradientType=1 );
```

What i really need is is a way to mix these?

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can just add them seperated with a comma:

```css
body {
    background: linear-gradient(transparent 50%, rgba(0, 0, 0, .1) 50%), linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(173,8,24,1) 33%, rgba(173,8,24,0.57) 62%, rgba(255,255,255,0.16) 89%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 100%);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(173, 8, 24, 0) 0%, rgba(173, 8, 24, 1) 100%);
```

see a [example here](https://jsfiddle.net/vh3x38jo/)